# Is there a way to paint inside the text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on the Flutter package and want to add an outlined wavy liquid text as below.

Is there any feature to add this in the Text widget?

[image]

Comment: There is no widget to do this automatically. You would have to clip the text to do this effect. Were you looking for this to be animated as well or just static? That would even more complex.

Comment: @JoãoSoares Yes, I want to make it animated also i.e. want to make wave move inside the text

Comment: That's actually quite complex. There is no Widget that will do that for you. I assume that it would need a ClipPath with QuadradicBeziers for the waves and then a cyclic animation would need to be implemented to run pixel perfect.

Comment: There are a few custom made widgets that you might be able to use like this one https://pub.dev/packages/circle_wave_progress

Comment: Can I just add the image of wave inside the text instead and animate it?

Answer (score 0):

there is this flutter package animated_text_kit 2.2.0. Which could be used to give a wavy animation to the text. I am leaving the link down below

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit

```
  width: 250.0,
  child: TextLiquidFill(
        text: 'LIQUIDY',
        waveColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        boxBackgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        textStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 80.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        boxHeight: 300.0,
  ),
);
```

Comment: I have only developed that animation (TextLiquidFill) and added it to the Animated Text Kit repository! Here's a blog for the same by me: https://link.medium.com/AfxVRdkWJ2